# Java Executor and Long-lived Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I've inherited some code that uses Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4); to run the 4 long-lived threads that do all the work of the application.

Is this recommended?  I've read the [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) book and there does not seem to be much guidance around how to manage long-lived application threads.

What is the recommended way to start and manage several threads that each live for the entire live of the application?

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that code is using `Executors`, it should be returning an `ExecutorService`

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREDS);
```

`ExecutorService` is an `Executor` that provides methods to manage termination and methods that can produce a Future for tracking progress of one or more asynchronous tasks.

As long as returned `ExecutorService` is performing graceful shutdown there should not be an issue.

You can check that your code is doing shutodwn by finding following in your code:

```
// This will make the executor accept no new threads
// and finish all existing threads in the queue
executor.shutdown();

// Wait until all threads are finish
executor.awaitTermination();
```

Cheers !!

Comment: My question is not whether it is SAFE to manage long-lived application threads this way but rather whether it is a best-practice.

Comment: Yes, as long as you take care of shutting down gracefully and closing all resources that are used by these threads.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your long-lived thread do some periodic job in a loop. What you can do is the following:

1. Make sure that each runnable in the pool checks the pool's state before looping.

`while( ! pool.isShutdown() ) { ... }`

Your runnable must thus have a reference to their parent pool.

2. Install a JVM shutdown hook with `Runtime.addShutdownHook()`. The hook calls `pool.shutdown()` then `pool.awaitTermination()`. The pool will transition to the SHUTDOWN state and eventually the threads will stop, after which it will transition to the TERMINATED state.

--

That said, I'm a bit suspicious of your 4 threads. Shouldn't there be only 1 long-live threads, which fetches tasks, and submits them to an executor service? Do you really have 4 different long-lived processes? (This consideration is orthogonal to the main question).

Comment: I just recently inherited this code and did not write it.  But I think your final point captures my concern well.  I'm wondering if the entire design is incorrect.