# Should I keep long running threads bare or use Executors?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on a streaming java application that is using several long running worker threads. The application receives data, processes it, and then sends it along toward a third party using their SDK. There is an *Engine* class that recieves data and submits it to *Workers*. The worker threads will live for as long as the application runs, which could be months if not years.

I have included sample code that represents this key part of this question.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class BarEngine implements Engine
{
   static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BarEngine.class);

   private static final int WORKER_COUNT = 5;
   private BlockingQueue<Map<String, Object>> queue;

   private FooWorker[] workers = new FooWorker[WORKER_COUNT];

   public BarEngine()
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < WORKER_COUNT; i++)
      {
         workers[i] = new FooWorker(i, queue);
         workers[i].start();
      }
   }

   // From Engine Interface
   @Override
   public void sendEvent(final Map<String, Object> data)
   {
      try
      {
         queue.put(data);
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e)
      {
         log.error("Unexpected Exception", e);
      }
   }

   // From Engine Interface
   @Override
   public void shutDown()
   {
      // Shuts down engine

   }

   public static class FooWorker extends Thread
   {
      static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FooWorker.class);

      private volatile boolean run = true;
      private int id;
      private BlockingQueue<Map<String, Object>> queue;
      private Client client;

      public FooWorker(int id, BlockingQueue<Map<String, Object>> queue)
      {
         this.id = id;
         this.queue = queue;
         client = Client.build(id);
      }

      @Override
      public void run()
      {
         setName("FooWorker-" + id);
         while (run)
         {
            try
            {
               Map<String, Object> data = queue.poll(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
               if (null != data)
               {
                  sendEvent(data);
               }
            }
            catch (Throwable e)
            {
               log.error("Unexpected Exception", e);
            }
         }
      }

      private void sendEvent(Map<String, Object> data)
      {
         try
         {
            client.submit(data);
         }
         catch (Throwable e)
         {
            log.error("Unexpected Exception", e);
         }
      }

      // dummy client classs
      public static class Client
      {
         public void submit(Map<String, Object> data)
         {
            // submits data
         }

         public static Client build(int id)
         {
            // Builds client
            return new Client();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have been doing a bit of research, and I have not found a satisfactory answer.

- [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) : Does not provide much guidance on long running threads.
- [When should we use Java's Thread over Executor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094867/when-should-we-use-javas-thread-over-executor/1095069) : Heavily suggest I should **ALWAYS** use an `Executor`. Does not cover the application long-life threads per se.
- [Java Executor and Long-lived Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366661/java-executor-and-long-lived-threads) : Discusses managing long lived threads with `Executor` but does not answer if one SHOULD manage long live threads with `Executor`

My question is: Should I keep these long running `Threads` *bare* like this? If not, what should I replace it with (Like `ExecutorService` or something else)?

Comment: Yeah definitely use an `ExecutorService`. Also if you really intend to be running threads for months if not years, you might want to brush up your skills first. Clearly there are a lot of things still unclear to you.

Comment: You've pretty much written some sort of executor service. Why do you have a timeout on your queue.poll? You could eliminate the whole queue/run/timeout bits and use an executor. Also, your shutdown doesn't shut anything down. I know you've left out some code, but your threads certainly aren't going to respect a shutdown. Plus, you have try, catch generic throwable, which calls a method, that does a try catch generic throwable. Definitely look into an ExecutorService.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your question, if you have threads which has the same lifetime of the application, in my opinion it doesn't matter if you are using a Thread or Executer service (which is again using Threads underneath) as long as you manage the thread's life cycle properly.

From design point of view your application falls in to software category what we called a "middleware". Generally a middleware application should be efficient as well as scalable, both which are essential qualities of such server yet you have ignored both. Your application's threads run busy-wait loops per thread keeping the CPU busy at all time. Even when the incoming load is very low this keeps happening. Which is a not good quality to have for such application.

Alternatively, I'm proposing you to use a `ThreadPool` implementation such as `ThreadPoolExecutor` which already have solved what you are trying to accomplish here. `ThreadPoolExecutor` leverages the functionality of a `BlockingQueue` if all initially fired up threads are busy at the moment. also it can stop threads if the load is low and fire up again if wanted. I have coded the structure of the design I'm proposing. Take a look at the following code. I assumed that `Client` is not thread-safe so I'm constructing a `Client` per thread. If your real client implementation is thread-safe you can use one client across all threads.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class BarEngine implements Engine {

    private static final int WORKER_COUNT = 5;
    private ExecutorService threadPool;

    public BarEngine() {
        this.threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, WORKER_COUNT, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100));
    }

    // From Engine Interface
    @Override
    public void sendEvent(final Map<String, Object> data) {
        threadPool.submit(new FooWorker(data));
    }

    // From Engine Interface
    @Override
    public void shutDown() {
        this.threadPool.shutdown();
        // Shuts down engine

    }

    public static class FooWorker implements Runnable {

        private final Client client;
        private final Map<String, Object> data;

        public FooWorker(Map<String, Object> data) {
            client = Client.build(Thread.currentThread().getId());
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (null != data) {
                    sendEvent(data);
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                //todo log
            }
        }

        private void sendEvent(Map<String, Object> data) {
            try {
                client.submit(data);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                //todo log
            }
        }

        // dummy client classs
        public static class Client {

            public void submit(Map<String, Object> data) {
                // submits data
            }

            public static Client build(long id) {
                // Builds client
                return new Client();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that ExecutorService is the way to go. However, OP asks about long-running threads and, in my experience, ExecutorServices never shut down cleanly when a long-running thread is active.

Comment: Not true. You can indeed cleanly shutdown an ExecutorService even when there is an active thread running.  You’ll have to use ‘shutdown’ , ‘awaitTermination’ and ‘shutdownNow’ methods together to first allow pool to shutdown gracefully first and then after a timeout forcefully shutdown with terminating the active thread.  Read the docs here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: I know what the docs say and have implemented their suggestion. In practice, it never shuts down cleanly, as evidenced by the tomcat "Timer-0 memory leak" log entries that everyone says to ignore, and the dozens of workarounds you'll find on this site, none of which fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you posted is exactly something for ExecutorService. Some advices:

- There are two main interfaces Executor, ExecutorService.
- Executors should be ended if you dont need them via shutdown/shutdownNow methods on ExecutorService interface. If not, you will face memleaks.
- Create your ExecutorService via Executors, for example:

  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

If you use Executor service, you can push data directly to ExecutorService via Runnable because ExecutorService doing queuing it self and split tasks into its workers...